# Count observations by group in a list of dataframes

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr, summarize

### **Problem**

I have a list of data frames. All of the dataframes have the same column names, but different numbers of rows. One column, called `pred` has the following four factors.

1. Apple
2. Cherry
3. Orange
4. Pear

I wish to count how many rows are 'apple', 'cherry' etc.

If I single out one dataframe (dataframe1), and perform the counts using:

```
count(dataframe1, pred)
```

I get the desired output:

```
pred                     n 
<fctr>                 <int>
Apple                   25          
Orange                  11          
Pear                    11          
Cherry                  12
```

This is how I would like the output for mutliple dataframes that are contained within a list. How can this be achieved? I have tried various options using the dyplr package, but tend to get the error.

`'Error in UseMethod("count") : no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "list"'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all data.frame have the same columns you can use this:

```
library(dplyr)


data1 <-data.frame(pred = sample(c("Apple","Cherry","Orange","Pear"),100,replace = TRUE))
data2 <-data.frame(pred = sample(c("Apple","Cherry","Orange","Pear"),100,replace = TRUE))
data3 <-data.frame(pred = sample(c("Apple","Cherry","Orange","Pear"),100,replace = TRUE))


list_of_dataframes <- list(data1,data2,data3)


bind_rows(list_of_dataframes,.id = "data") %>% 
  count(data,pred)
```

Comment: I seem to get the error `Error in UseMethod("as.quoted") : no applicable method for 'as.quoted' applied to an object of class "function"`. Any ideas why this may be so?

Comment: When trying my example or adapting my code to your scenario?

Comment: Both actually..

Comment: Never mind, it was just a problem in generating by dataframe. Works now :)

Answer (score 0):

With `lapply` you may use `table` and coerce it `as.data.frame`.

```
lapply(dat, \(x) as.data.frame(table(x$pred, dnn='pred')))
# [[1]]
#     pred Freq
# 1  Apple    5
# 2 Cherry    2
# 3 Orange    3
# 
# [[2]]
#     pred Freq
# 1  Apple    5
# 2 Cherry    4
# 3 Orange    1
# 4   Pear    5
# 
# [[3]]
# p    red Freq
# 1  Apple    3
# 2 Cherry    5
# 3 Orange    7
# 4   Pear    3
```

---

*Data:*

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- lapply(c(10, 15, 18), \(x) 
              data.frame(
                pred=sample(c('Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Cherry'), x, replace=TRUE),
                x=runif(x))
              )
```